# Failure - not installed for 0

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to uninstall a few Google APKs that were preinstalled on an older smartphone I have. 
I must do it via ADB because it's not possible to do it via regular uninstall

I found a guide on how to remove those APKs using ADB, but when I try to remove a certain Google package, for example `com.google.apps.plus`, using the following command:

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.apps.plus
```

I get the following error: `Failure - not installed for 0`

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app installation: Unknown failure (Failure - not installed for 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077518/android-app-installation-unknown-failure-failure-not-installed-for-0)

Comment: The above post specifically speaks about MIUI. This is NOT a duplicate

Comment: There's a more generic solution right below the accepted answer, have you tried by disabling `Instant run`?

Comment: that means when app were installed the user was not  a 0 (device owner) it could be another user that you don't know. Try using 1 0r 2 or primary instead

Comment: In case you have more than one user on your phone, DO NOT use the `--user` option, this  is one of the reasons you might get that error, that the app is installed for one user and not the other; the other reason is that you have a typo in the package ID.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing the same issue. For solving this problem just make sure that you have the latest USB drivers for your device. You can get your drivers from [Android Devs Website](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html). This is a list of all major OEM's compiled by google. Then download ADB tools from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip). After ensuring the above steps, download any App Inspector application from play store for getting the exact package name of the apps.

In your device's Developer Options,turn on USB debugging. Open Windows PowerShell where you have downloaded the ADB tools.To see if ADB is working use `.\adb` command.

Then use `.\adb shell` for activating adb shell. Then use this command for removing the packages `pm uninstall -k --user 0 <package name>`. You will get package name in the App Inspector application.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the weverse app, what I did was:

1. Open the app (it required me to update it)
2. Update the app in the PlayStore
3. Close the app Uninstall with the common command

   pm uninstall -k --user 0 "package name"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app is installed and also not "disabled".