# Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)) Error while Installing APKs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, android-manifest

My app had compiled and then it was installing the apk in my phone when a popup came asking me that the new installation will uninstall the previous version and then install the new one. I clicked OK but then after a while it shows this error:-

```
01/14 10:43:22: Launching app 
$ adb install-multiple -r -t
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
E:\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
E:\root\Desktop\projects\Track\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.saveme.rehaan.track
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674))
Error while Installing APKs
```

Can someone please help me as to how i can solve this.

Comment: In android studio go to File - click on invalidate Caches/ Restart @Rehaan Mazid

Comment: @Rehaan Mazid, Disable Instant Run on Android Studio, File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment then there on the right side you will Instant Run then Just Uncheck Instant Run.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077519/1778421

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44202530/1778421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly same issue after moving the project files from one folder to another one and I solved it like this:

**1. File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment.**

**2. Instant Run -> disable "I found it's enabled, then I disabled it".**

**3. Apply -> OK**

nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

## Try below following steps:

1. While installing any app from play store it shows popup in order
   to uninstall some apps to make free space for new app.
2. Uninstall some apps from your phone in order to free some space.
3. Clean your project (Build --> clean Project)
4. Run Again

### If above solution does not work

5. Generate Debug apk.
6. Transfer apk in your phone and install from there.
7. Uninstall other apps until your app does not install.

   ------------ Hope it will work for you---------------