# error Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)) Error while Installing APKs

Tags: java, android, apk

Could somebody tell me what that means?

Everything went fine, I haven't changed anyhing and it just happened,
this is the code in Binder 565:

```
try {
    res = onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
} catch (RemoteException | RuntimeException e) {
    if (LOG_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.", e);
    }
    if ((flags & FLAG_ONEWAY) != 0) {
        if (e instanceof RemoteException) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Binder call failed.", e);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.", e);
        }
    } else {
        reply.setDataPosition(0);
        reply.writeException(e);
    }
    res = true;
}
```

Comment: Show your stack trace and associated code.

Comment: I had the same issue when I moved my project folder. In my case, **Build->Clean Project** fixed the issue.

Comment: The answer from linen  worked for me ! Thanks !

Answer (score 89):

I had this issue when I was trying to install apk on emulator and I was always getting error messages that I need to uninstall the old version of my app's apk.

I solved it like this:

**1. File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment.**

**2. Instant Run -> disable  "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy".**

**3. Apply -> OK**

After that you can clean the project **(Build -> Clean project)** and re-enable instant run to get the instant run working again.

### EDIT (Android Studio 3.0)

Disable Instant Run ([Android Document](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html))

To disable Instant Run:

1. Open the **Settings** or **Preferences** dialog. (For Mac, **Android Studio** -> **Preferences**)
2. Navigate to **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Instant Run**.
3. Uncheck the box next to **Enable Instant Run**.

Comment: In my case, I have to re-enable the instant run after disabling to make it work.

Comment: Anyone knows why this happens? I would like to know. And what should people do, if they happen to want to use Instant run?

Comment: As @Nevdev mentioned, you need to clean the project (Build -> clean project) then re-enable "Instant run"!

Comment: Along with this pls check that you have enabled "INSTALL VIA USB" option in 'Developer Options' in Mobile (especially if you are using Xiomi devices)

Comment: @Tsur Yohananov even this question asked before 1 year, 6 months ago 
If this is a correct answer, You should accept it as correct answer

Comment: I have the same problem, and that was enought for me to run "Build -> Clean Project". And the error has gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:702))
Error while Installing APK

There could be 2 Possible solutions for this error :

Solution 1: Check that you have enabled "INSTALL VIA USB" option in 'Developer Options' in Mobile (especially if you are using Xiomi devices)

Solution 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46102740/5582162 - Solution posted by @Mithor.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error message. Turns out my systems and/or emulator ran out of storage space and it's couldn't install the APK. Mithor's solution revealed to out of space memory error. I was then able to enable instant run after freeing up some space.

Comment: This is exactly what happened in my case

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I cleaned the project, then rebuilt the code and it worked.
And in `Mi or Xiomi` phone just enabled "INSTALL VIA USB" in developer option.

Comment: yes, worked for me as well, I was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i disabled INSTANT RUN and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution worked with mine but the problem reoccurred on enable it back even when the app ran successfully. Then, following the **Build Project** documentation in [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/) as advised by Dhaval Jardosh, performing a clean project the app started to run with the **Instant Run** enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. My phone space was very low. I just increased my phone space and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because your device and your JNI do not match. For example, your device is X86 ABI, but you use the JNI for ARM.

Comment: This answer was originally in Chinese. Translation courtesy of Google Translate plus a bit of guesswork. The poster may not be able to answer follow-up questions in English.

Comment: This site is English-only. Please only post in English.

Comment: @bummi So that you know, the consensus is that we should *not* translate posts for users. For more information, please see: [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680)

Answer (score 0):

This crash appeared suddenly without any reason. I just restarted Android Studio and my device ; and it worked. I don't know if both solutions or just one of them is required.

Check also that there is enough space disk on your device to install the app. Actually, even if your app is 10 Mo, there might be this problem if you have 300 Mo or less available on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message. In my case, it was because I changed the folder of my project. I moved the project to another folder and when I tried to install apk to my device it failed with a similar error. Deleting of data, uninstalling the old app, cleaning the project and building the new apk helped in my case.