# android studio wont install app with code android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After a little of playing with java codes in android studio, suddenly it stopped installing apps on avd. I can have the apk output and install it on my phone(there I get the play protect error of unconfirmed developer ) as I disabled play protect on my avd. I have no idea what the problem is.
every time I try to do that android studio retries to uninstall the app from avd and the app is not on the apps list of avd device the error code is this:

```
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697))
```

I have done the solution on this post but it didn't help.
this post:`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202530/error-unknown-failure-at-android-os-binder-exectransactbinder-java565-error`

**Edit**

another error raised:
[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOdZy.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)) Error while Installing APKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202530/error-unknown-failure-at-android-os-binder-exectransactbinder-java565-error)

Comment: no i have checked that before it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that with the ioutils that i was adding on dependencies some how made compatibility problem with the system cpu (the problem that i didn't have on my android phone)so next time it happens to any one first check your dependencies by going to:

```
File -> project structure -> dependencies tab
```

delete any unusually item there that did the trick for me

**Note That it may make your app to act abnormally**